# C# false if statement being used

Tags: c#, if-statement, runtime-error

SOLVED: the code was excecuted via events every 10 ms, increasing the time it takes between events solved the issue.

I´m experiencing an odd `IndexOutOfRangeException` which shouldn´t be happening. Code inside an if statement is being used even though the statement itself is ´false´. Is this a known problem? If so, how can I fix this?

The error occurs when counter (an `int`) is 0, thus requesting `element -1` from the `array` Lights.

Code:

```
 if (counter  > 0)
    {
    Console.WriteLine("counter-1 is groter dan 0");
    int i = counter - 1;
    Lights[i].setState(0);
    }
```

Comment: Is 'counter' accessed from any other threads?

Comment: I'm sorry, but that cannot be right. If the if-statement is false, the code inside the statement will not be executed, unless you have a multi-threading problem. Could you post more of your code so we can see what you are doing?

Comment: An image of the error can be seen here: http://s13.postimg.org/a0frmariv/indexoutofrange.jpg I was also very surprised to see it.. The application is a single-threaded application and counter is a private variable.

Comment: how the counter is set? Which else function access it?

Comment: does cleaning and rebuilding the solution helps ?

Comment: Don't think we can suss this out without seeing lots more of the code.

Comment: @MatthewWatson I think it is actually a **lot** easier than it looks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A timer fired events every 10ms. This created the posibility of:

- The program getting inside the if-statement during event A.
- A new event B being fired and the CPU taking care of event B.
- Event B changing the counter to a negative value, thus making the if-statement false.
- The CPU changing to take care of event A.
- The program is now inside the if-statement even though the if-statement itself is false.

The problem has been solved by making events fire less often.

Comment: The problem has not ben solved It's just les likely that it will occur

Comment: Using a mutex to lock the statement could have been an option, but this would have required me to lock every single statement which might cause an issue. The program was designed to run at specific hardware, thus its limitations were known and would not change during the duration of the project.

Answer (score 1):

Unless counter is accessed/manipulated in a multi-threaded way - this should be an impossible state.

you can always try making the assignment & check in one place:

```
 var index = 0;

 if ((index = (counter - 1))  > 0)
 {
    Lights[index].setState(0);
 }
```

Comment: This just makes the code harder to read and harder to debug imho.  It does nothing for thread safety.

Answer (score 1):

If that is a single-threaded application without any other code mutating `counter`, then the most likely explanation is that `Lights` is simply not long enough. For example, if `counter` is `1` (which is, I think you'll agree, `> 0` - so the `if` test will pass), and `Lights` is a zero-length array, then `Lights[i]` (`Lights[0]`) will raise this exception - or if `counter` is `200` but `Lights.Length` is `199` (or fewer) - as `Lights[i]` (`Lights[199]`) is outside of the range `0`-`198`.

Check `Lights.Length`.

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought! But when I looked at the error message in the debugger that the op posted, I became very unsure! (I can't repost the link here for some reason...)

Answer (score 0):

If there are no other threads changing `counter` in the background, then the only possible explanation is that the `Lights[]` collection has zero size.

Try checking the length of `Lights` before accessing its elements.

Comment: but does that explain the code being executed despite if condition evaluating to false

Comment: @tariq I don't believe that's what's happening. I think what's actually happening is that `Lights[]` has zero size. But I agree the message in the linked image does look very odd. The debugger is definitely showing counter as zero. I suspect some weird build problem may be masking the true cause.

Comment: @MatthewWatson: I think the tooltip shows counter as 0 because it was 1 before the if statement was entered, then it was decremented (the current line is the one after the decrement). The other tooltip imho is being evaluated at mouseover, so at that point in time `counter > 0` is `false`

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
int i=0;
if (counter  > 0)
{
 Console.WriteLine("counter-1 is groter dan 0");
 i = counter - 1;
 Lights[i].setState(0);
}
```